# Is self-promotion spam?

Tags: discussion

This question is triggered by me flagging a post, that does not try to answer the question and contains a link to a camera comparison, a moderator reviewing and declining it and @studiohack removing the link in an edit (see [the review history](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/posts/20034/revisions)).

Now I am confused when to use the spam flag. Its description seems to fit this case perfectly:

> spam
>   Exists only to promote a product or service, does not disclose the author's affiliation.

Except that maybe one wants to argue that a camera comparison may not count as a service - in my opinion it does.

Where should I draw the line?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Technically **no, in this case,** because the author **disclosed their affiliation**.

> **I** reviewed some good camera for hiking

On the other hand, the link really doesn't have any useful information for the answer, so there is no harm in removing it, and if the answer was written with the idea of creating links back to their page, removing it will quickly shut that down.

I have seen one person edit the link back in later and so I let a mod know, but based on my experience, I highly doubt that this user will ever post anything again.

It also doesn't answer the question so we may as well delete it.

Comment: Good point, kind of missed that implicit disclosure.

Answer (score 3):

I'd point you at [Limits for self-promotion in answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57497/limits-for-self-promotion-in-answers)

> #### May I promote products I am affiliated with here?
>
> The community generally frowns on overt self-promotion and tends to vote it down and flag it as spam, so be careful. Post good, relevant answers, and if they happen to be about your product, so be it. However, you must disclose your affiliation with the product in your answers. Also, if a huge percentage of your posts include a mention of your product, you're clearly here for the wrong reasons. Our advertising rates are quite reasonable; [contact our ad sales team](https://stackoverflow.com/about/contact) for details. We also offer [free vote-based advertising for open source projects](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/open-source-advertising).